# How to get SSH Putty to properly display python tkinter GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter, ssh, debian

I'm trying to run tkinter 8.6.11 under python 3.9.2 on Debian 11.

At the server console, in python:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter._test()
```

produces the expected GUI popup window.

But, from an SSH Putty session at my Windows 10 Pro 64  workstation, the same code produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4557, in _test
    root = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: You need to run a [*X Server*](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) in Windows and then create a PuTTY session with *X11 forwarding* enabled. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty) may help.

Comment: You can use [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) which includes *X Server*.

Comment: Actually, Xming IS an X11 server, and it's working well now.

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded and installed Xming from https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/

and then followed the instructions at
https://www1.udel.edu/it/research/training/config_laptop/puTTY.shtml

to configure SSH Putty to use XMing for the server session.

The GUI popup now properly displays on the Windows workstation.

Comment: This answer would be useless if the udel.edu web page disappeared. You should [edit] your answer to describe the steps without referring to third-party sites.

Comment: But, would such not cause somebody else to comment that I was violating copyright by doing so. In many ways, you "just can't win." (sigh).